# ubuntu 18.04 dns showing loop back

Tags: dns, netplan

I edited the yaml file in /etc/netplan to include the name servers. It applied without error. However when I do nslookup > server I get the loop back (127.0.0.1) I need it to be my DNS servers as this is joined to the domain. I had also changed the link of the /etc/resolv.conf but when I reboot it, it goes back to the old settings. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the link and created a /etc/resolv.conf and added the name servers. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 always uses systemd-resolved as a local resolver, and the nameservers specified in netplan config are fed to resolved rather than listed directly in /etc/resolv.conf.  It is not recommended to bypass this by making /etc/resolv.conf a file.

Comment: But according to this site, you're supposed to disable systemd-resolved when joining a domain....https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain/

Comment: I know of no reason why you should need to disable resolved to join a domain, and this third-party how-to doesn't explain.  Unless you have a specific problem when using resolved (in which case, please file a bug report!), I still recommend keeping it enabled.